# How to change the design of getPriceHtml function in Magento 1.x

Tags: magento-1, price, grid, design

I have got an issue with **design of price** in grid.

When I get in to the design page to redesign the price showing format, it calls following function to call the design.

```
<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product, true) ?>
```

But I am not able to see where the function is defined.

Thanks in advance!